# Assigning resources to MS Project 2007

Tags: microsoft-project, resources, microsoft-project-2007

I'm planning a redesign of a site in Project 2007. I have three developers to hand, all with the same skills.

There are about 80 templates to be rendered as part of the redesign, and each template has been added as a project task. Each of these tasks can be done by any of the 3 devs, and each will take a day (with a few exceptions). There is no order in which the tasks must be completed, so there are no predecessor rules.

I'd like to be able to assign tasks to a 'Developer' resource group, and for Project to see that three tasks can be done at once (as the group has three resources members) and queue the tasks as such.

Googling leads me to Team Assignment, but that appears to be part of Project Server. Surely I can do this in standalone Project?

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the chapter 4 of [Project 2010 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=68384).

Unfortunately the fee is $99.95, but you can search it on the web.